# How can I inset a specific number into a executive code (ARM)?

Tags: file, arm, execution

I have two executive files which there is a little difference between both files.

I want to distinguish two files by inserting a number in the specific place of the executive file.

Is it possible? If then, how can I do that?

Comment: Of course.  There is always a notion of a basic block and padding.  Typically compiled files are at least 4 byte aligned with the extra space between files being filed with zero or random values.  You can always add numbers at the end of the file.  Some issue are; Do you have source?  What operating system/environment?  You have given too few details.

Comment: Hi, artless.. Do you need my source? I don't think that you need my source for supporting this issue. My system is ST32F2XX(based on ARM CPU). Do you need other information? Thanks for your concerning.

Comment: What compiler and linker are you using? It is possible to define an area in your linker script and place certain things there, but the instructions for doing so will depend on the software you're using.